# Tracking Differences of Times Between Hits in Google Analytics Data

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

So I am using Google Analytics data on BigQuery and want to be able to track the difference between hits, grouped by a custom dimension I have that can change within a session. If I have data that looks like

```
__________________________
| customDimension1 | Time |
|__________________|______|
| abc              |  t1  |
| abc              |  t2  |
| def              |  t3  |
| def              |  t4  |
| def              |  t5  |
| abc              |  t6  |
| abc              |  t7  |
|__________________|______|
```

I want to be able to get something like

```
_______________________________________
| customDimension1 | Time | Difference |
|__________________|______|____________|
| abc              |  t1  |  t2 - t1   |
| abc              |  t2  |  t3 - t2   |
| def              |  t3  |  t4 - t3   |
| def              |  t4  |  t5 - t4   |
| def              |  t5  |  t6 - t5   |
| abc              |  t6  |  t7 - t6   |
| abc              |  t7  |      0     |
|__________________|______|____________|
```

Any good ideas how to do this without going through Dataflow/Dataproc for transformations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL    (and assumes Time column is of TIMESTAMP data type)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(IFNULL(LEAD(Time) OVER(ORDER BY Time), Time), Time, SECOND) AS Difference 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'abc' customDimension1, TIMESTAMP '2020-08-26 23:03:21.938228 UTC' Time UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2020-08-26 23:03:23.938228 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'def', '2020-08-26 23:03:26.938228 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'def', '2020-08-26 23:03:28.938228 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'def', '2020-08-26 23:03:41.938228 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2020-08-26 23:03:51.938228 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', '2020-08-26 23:03:55.938228 UTC' 
)
SELECT *, 
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(IFNULL(LEAD(Time) OVER(ORDER BY Time), Time), Time, SECOND) AS Difference 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row customDimension1    Time                            Difference   
1   abc                 2020-08-26 23:03:21.938228 UTC  2    
2   abc                 2020-08-26 23:03:23.938228 UTC  3    
3   def                 2020-08-26 23:03:26.938228 UTC  2    
4   def                 2020-08-26 23:03:28.938228 UTC  13   
5   def                 2020-08-26 23:03:41.938228 UTC  10   
6   abc                 2020-08-26 23:03:51.938228 UTC  4    
7   abc                 2020-08-26 23:03:55.938228 UTC  0
```

Comment: yes, just remembered that that that is not included in check-marking. Thank you very much!